# Swagger UI API-DOC not working no matter what

Tags: spring-boot, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I have a Spring-Boot application which has some rest endpoints , everything is working fine (apis.yaml , application.properties) .... even :

```
http://localhost:8083/api/v1.0/api-swagger
```

returns the JSON file as required [image]

On the other hand

```
http://localhost:8083/api-doc/index.html?url=/api/v1.0/api-swagger
```

Is displaying 404

[image]

---

But the strangest thing of all is that it is working on every other
 computer except mine and I have the same settings and everything .

I also tried:

**1 )** Suspecting that it may have to be something with Browsers cache I tried 4
 different browsers and private mode.

**2 )** Deleted and redownloaded Maven Jars for
Swagger in case they are corrupted .

My question is what other it may be ..... ?

Any further information you need please ask me .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So the project i am building on has a dependency which defines

**SwaggerConfiguration.java** :

```
@Configuration
public class SwaggerConfiguration {

    public final static String SWAGGER_ENDPOINT = "/api/v1.0/api-swagger";

    @Configuration
    public static class SwaggerWebFluxConfigurer implements WebFluxConfigurer {

        @Override
        public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
            registry.addResourceHandler("/api-doc" + "/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/3.18.2/");

            registry.addResourceHandler("/swagger/examples/**")
                    .addResourceLocations("classpath:/swagger/examples/");
        }
    }

}
```

Now all the magic happened here

```
registry.addResourceHandler("/api-doc" + "/**")
                        .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/swagger-ui/3.18.2/");
```

, so i forgot to change the dependency on pom.xml so ...... in the Maven dependency was `Swagger-ui 3.17`.

Now added the correct one :

[image]

---

And guess what .... no errors ... nothing . Well at least remember to check that in case you have the same problem.